ROS 2 and Gazebo: rviz2 Not Receiving /camera/image_raw and /scan Topics and Fixed Frame Configuration Issues
I am currently facing issues integrating camera and LiDAR sensors from Gazebo into rviz2 within ROS 2. Despite the sensors functioning correctly in Gazebo, I am unable to receive data from the /camera/image_raw and /scan topics in rviz2. This is preventing the visualization of camera images and LiDAR scans in rviz2.
Additionally, I am experiencing problems with the Fixed Frame settings. The default Fixed Frame is set to world, but changing it to any other frame results in the robot's position being altered incorrectly. This issue becomes more pronounced when I set the Fixed Frame to laser_frame, which completely changes the robot's position.
Confirmed that the topics are being published in ROS 2 using ros2 topic list.
<link name="camera_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.05 0.05 0.05"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin xyz="-0.15 0.12 0.05  "/>
      <material name="green">
        <color rgba="0 0.8 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.1"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0.0" izz="0.01"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>



  <!-- Camera Joint with updated origin // ${-pi/2} -->
  <joint name="computer_to_camera_joint" type="fixed">
      <origin xyz="-0.15 0.12 0.05" rpy="0 0 -2.356"/>
      <parent link="computer"/>
      <child link="camera_link"/>
  </joint>

  <joint name="camera_optical_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="camera_link"/>
    <child link="camera_link_optical"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.15 0.12  0.05" rpy="-1.5708 0 0"/> 
  </joint>

  <link name="camera_link_optical"></link>

   <!-- Gazebo Configuration for Camera -->
  <gazebo reference="camera_link">
    <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
    <sensor name="camera" type="camera">
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <update_rate>10</update_rate>
      <camera>
        <horizontal_fov>1.089</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <format>R8G8B8</format>
          <width>640</width>
          <height>480</height>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.05</near>
          <far>8.0</far>
        </clip>
      </camera>
      <plugin name="camera_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
        <frame_name>camera_link_optical</frame_name>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>


  <link name="lidar">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="0.1" length="0.2"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.09"/>
      <material name="yellow">
        <color rgba="0.8 0.8 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.2"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.05" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.05" iyz="0.0" izz="0.05"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>

 
  <joint name="lidar_to_laser" type="fixed">
    <parent link="lidar"/>
    <child link="laser_frame"/>
    <origin xyz="0.1 0 0.175" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>

    <link name="laser_frame">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.04"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="red">
        <color rgba="0.8 0 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.04"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.1"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0.0" izz="0.01"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <gazebo reference="laser_frame">
    <sensor name="laser" type="ray">
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <visualize>false</visualize>
      <update_rate>10</update_rate>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>360</samples>
            <min_angle>-3.14</min_angle>
            <max_angle>3.14</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.3</min>
          <max>8</max>
        </range>
      </ray>
      <plugin name="laser_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_ray_sensor.so">
        <ros>
          <argument>~/out:=scan</argument>
        </ros>
        <output_type>sensor_msgs/LaserScan</output_type>
        <frame_name>laser_frame</frame_name>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>




